# How to run a load test with ApacheBench

Tags: node.js, go, benchmarking, apachebench

Please, how can I use ApacheBench to do load testing assuming I want to test the HTTP capabilities of Node and Go?. Note: I have installed AB, I just don't know how to run the test.

Node:

```
  var http = require("http");
  http.createServer(function(request,response) {
  response.writeHeader(200);
  response.write("You requested " + request.url);
  response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "You requested %s", r.URL.Path)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: use something better than `ab`? `wrk`, `httpperf`, `boom`, `siege`, `weighttp`, `vegeta` come to mind. I prefer `wrk` and have been experimenting with `vegeta` since it has a constant request rate (there's a wrk fork somewhere to do that too)

Comment: @JimB what's wrong with ab?

Comment: To start, it's only http/1.0 (doesn't do keepalive by default) has trouble with chunked encodings, and doesn't perform as well as many others. Your contrived Go server can respond faster than `ab` can test, so all you're testing is `ab`.

Comment: Just ran it myself, and `wrk` reports response times in the 200us range, and `ab` reports them in the 70ms range. That's 2 order of magnitude in error, and you're not even yet handling the problem of the request _rate_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do ab -n [number of requests] -c [number of concurrent requests] [url]:[port]

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://localhost:8080/
```